# Preventing Android WebView navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to inject some Javascript into a WebView after a page loads that will prevent the user from navigating away from that page.

There are links on this page that use Javascript to navigate the user, so `WebViewClient::shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not sufficient.  It doesn't even get fired.

```
private final String javascript = "javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return false; };"

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        getWebView().loadUrl(javascript);
}
```

I was hoping the above code would work, but it does not.  Tapping on different elements still allows the user to navigate away from the starting url.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The android webview follows the same rules as all the other browsers, which means `onbeforeunload` wont work that way.  You have to tie in an event that prevents navigation on an element basis.

Assuming your links are in fact `a` tags you can do something like this on page load

```
var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {
    Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }, 
        false);
}
```

If the links are not anchors this wont work, but if you are trying to code around a UI designed by someone else that you dont have access to this stuff happens

Comment: So I think this won't quite work for me.  Something I did not specify in my original post is that I'm trying to capture the user tapping on navigation links and launching the Android Browser app with that url.  I've successfully done this.  However, when the user hits the back button and returns to my application, the WebView has moved forward, too.

Comment: I have tried programmatically calling `goBack()` on the WebView and that works.  However, the user will see the page switch back and forth and it isn't a great experience.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by setting a custom webview client :

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // put your code here
            return true; //Indicates WebView do NOT load the url;
        }
    });
```